# Connection to http://10.x.x.x/path/file.pl refused

Tags: android, http

I'm trying to create a login in Android with a local server. This is my first attempt to develope Android Apps. So please be patient with me :P
This is my doInBackground method in my UserLoginTask task:

```
try {
    Log.v("Login", "Start http request");

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.x.x.x/path/file.pl");

    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "login"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg1", mUser));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg2", mPassword));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    Log.v("Login", response.toString());

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.v("Error", e.getMessage().toString());
    return false;
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.v("Error", e.getMessage().toString());
    return false;
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.v("Error", e.getMessage().toString());
    return false;
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.v("Error", e.getMessage().toString());
    return false;
}
```

Everytime I start this, I get `Start http request` and `Connection to http://10.x.x.x refused`. And this are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

UPDATE 1:

I think I've found the problem...Apache crashed for some reason. No http request for Android devices on Windows Server :P

Comment: Are the x's in http://10.x.x.x/ really there, or just to hide the real IP?  Is there actually an HTTP server listening at http://10.x.x.x/?

Comment: Don't log only the exception message. Add the exception itself as a third parameter to the log call so you get full exception prints, including any possible nested exceptions. As to the error itself, connection refused means that there wasn't anything listening in the port you were trying to connect to.

Comment: @JanPeter FYI 10.0.0.0/8 is a private address range, just like 192.168.0.0/16 and 172.16.0.0/12.  They're not internet-routable.  Does 10.x.x.x represent the address of the Android device itself or another computer on the same local network?  Is there actually an HTTP server running there?  If on another computer, does the firewall on that computer allow port 80 ingress?

Comment: I know. The server is in my local network. Via VPN.
But I think I found the problem...Updated my main post

Answer (score 0):

I am just a novice like you(may be more then you :p). However, what I understood from your code and the error is that, the problem is not with your code. The problem is with the server. I meant, your request to that server has nothing wrong but for some reason the server is not accepting your request or responding. Did you have the proper IP address associated with port number. If you so, then check server configuration(may be).

Don't know how much it helped, but this is the best I could understand.

Comment: The problem is, that I already created such a app for Windows Phone 8. Also with the post method. But I should give the get method a try :/ 
UPDATE: It doesn't changed anything :(

Comment: Then boss, am not the right person. You better shout out in some google developer group on Google+ if you do not get your job done. Hope that you would find your solution soon. :)

Comment: Yeahh. I found it^^ Apache crashed :/